# Positioning an element at the bottom of div (not parent) - Twitter Bootstrap v3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to positioning an element (button) at the bottom of a div, please check my code to understand exactly that I want to achieve:

```
<body>
    ...
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-md-3>
            ...
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-4 narrow'>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-md-4'>
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-4'>
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-4'>
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-md-12'>
                    <a href="#">
                        <button>I'M THE ELEMENT!</button>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-5'>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</body>
```

I can't set `position:absolute`, because that breaks the visual style of my project.

Look this image that I have prepared:

[image: Layout]

**NOTE:** The blue columns have variable height... For that reason I want to positionting the button at the bottom of those columns. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You want the `.narrow`  `div` to be always the same height as it siblings and the `button` on the bottom of it, right?

Comment: Did you add additional css to bootstrap? If not, this code already does exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: @MaksymStepanenko the `.narrow` `div` have a dynamic heights, I want the button at bottom of that div, behind the blue columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options, but unfortunately neither are possible within the constraints of the Bootstrap framework.

**Option 1: Flex-box**

[Flex-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) was designed to solve problems exactly like this and is the way of the future for creating layouts in CSS.

I have implemented your image mockup using flex-box:

[Live example.](http://codepen.io/mjswensen/pen/KwbpRO)

Here is the code from my example:

```
<section class="main">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="middle-top-container">
      <div class="middle-top-column"></div>
      <div class="middle-top-column"></div>
      <div class="middle-top-column"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="middle-bottom-container">
      <button>I'm the element!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</section>

.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 600px;
}

.main .left {
  flex-grow: 3;
  border: 2px solid #f00;
}

.main .middle {
  flex-grow: 4;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.main .middle .middle-top-container {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.main .middle .middle-top-container .middle-top-column {
  border: 2px solid #00f;
  flex-grow: 4;
}

.main .middle .middle-bottom-container {
  border: 2px solid gold;
  text-align: center;
}

.main .right {
  flex-grow: 5;
  border: 2px solid #0f0;
}
```

(Note that you will need to add the appropriate [vendor prefixes](http://davidwalsh.name/vendor-prefixes) for the `flex`-related properties for best browser support, but my implementation works in Chrome as-is.)

What this will mean for you: for this part of your page, you will need to remove the Bootstrap layout classes and use an implementation similar to mine (you can of course use Bootstrap layout for other parts of your page as desired).

[More information about `flex-box` with visual examples.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

**Option 2: Positioning Context**

It is possible to use `position: absolute;`, but again, you will have to stray from using Bootstrap layout classes for this part of your page. What it would entail is setting `position: relative;` on the containing element, the one that wraps the center of your outermost three-column layout (corresponding to `<div class="middle">...</div>` in my implementation) to establish positioning context, then using `position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;` on the element containing your button.

Please note that the flex-box approach is less fragile, more future-facing, and preferable over this option in my opinion and experience.

Answer (score -2):

You can use float

`#div_button {float: bottom;}`

this should make the button at the bottom.  Just make sure the button is inside the same div as your blue ones.

Comment: That did not work, the problem is that the divs have dynamic heights. Is responsive design.

Comment: Unfortunately, `bottom` is not a [valid value for `float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float).

Comment: `float` can be right/left (or none), with optional inheritance from parent, but never `bottom`.